# template and macro in C++

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Not a computer science background, I am a little bit confused with templates when there are macros involved:

Considering the following code:

```
template <int Signal1, int Signal2>
void my_add(int & x, int y)
{
#if Signal1==1||Signal2==1
    x+=y;
#endif 
}

//And call the template, e.g.: my_add<1, 1>(x, 3);
```

The problem is, it seems that the `#if` macro does not work as intended, as if the `#if` macro test always return `false`, so the outcome is `my_add<1,1>` does nothing.

Anyone could explain why this is the case? (`MSVC 2012`).

Comment: Not sure why the question is downvoted. Seeing how many bad answers were given, it's clearly confusing to a number of people, including people who thought they knew how this works.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you actually want, and it's not trivial:

```
template <bool defaultCase> class Adder
{
   static void my_add(int & x, int y) { }
};

template < > class Adder<true>
{
   static void my_add(int & x, int y) { x += y; }
};

template <int Signal1, int Signal2>
void my_add(int & x, int y)
{
   Adder<Signal1==1 || Signal2==1>::my_add(x,y);
}
```

This is a partial specialization, and it requires a class template. Function templates don't have partial specialization because it interferes with overloading, but here the template arguments do not participate in overloading.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the types Signal1/Signal2 used by the template, with the symbolic constant used by the preprocessor - two different "domains".

The macro symbols are evaluated during the preprocessing stage (prior to the actual compilation) and use symbols.

The template types are defined during the compilation stage (if the template is instanciated.)

Although you use the same "name" for both, the preprocessor still does not have any Signal1/2 symbol defined.

The following link may be of help:
[Preprocessor directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Answer (score 1):

In Short: Templates are evaluated *at compiletime*, but anything starting with `#` is a *pre-* processor statement and is evaluated *right before* the code is compiled. I hope you see that these two can't mix the way you intended.

In your example you are comparing the tokens `Signal1` and `1`. Now this would make sense if `Signal1` was itself a makro and set somewhere else to be replaced with `1`, `2` etc. depending on some condition, but that's not the case.

Comment: Templates are very much evaluated (instantiated) at compile time.

Comment: You have a problem here as you haven't understood templates at all, but that's for you to research ;)

Comment: Ah, you're right, I was so fixated on it being different times, that I messed up... will fix

Comment: OK, and the other thing about not understanding templates was completely wrong as well -_-

Comment: Well, it's now talking about a string comparison, and that's again wrong. `#if 1+1 == 2` is true.

Comment: I guess he meant to simplify "token", to indicate that these symbols don't participate in the compilation-stage C++ semantic interpretations.

Comment: Yeah, I admit it's badly worded and might be misleading... I'm gonna go with token, thanks Lightness ;)

Answer (score 0):

The macro doesn't care or even know about the template. Macros just work by search-and-replacing characters and lines in your source code file, right at the point before it's about to be compiled.

At that point, no variables have values, no functions are being run, and no template arguments have values. It's analogous to how PHP code is *preprocessed*: the underlying HTML and the PHP logic are completely separate from each other, and cannot interact.

It can be confusing because your macro code *looks like* it's "inside" the function template, but really it's not: the two things live on different planes of existence!

When no macro `Signal1` or `Signal2` exist (which is presumably the case here), the code that gets output from the preprocessor and then used for processing is this:

```
template <int Signal1, int Signal2>
void my_add(int & x, int y)
{
}
```

Answer (score -2):

<strike>The macro cannot get type info. Its invoked before the compiler. What Signal1 and Signal2 refer to in your macro have nothing to do with template parameters.</strike>

Use`#define Signal1 1` and `x+=y` will take effect in your template.
Remember - This happens before the template is expanded based on your usage.

Edit: The question was about partial specialization. Let this serve as a gentle "don't pounce upon a question" reminder.

Comment: `template <int 1, int Signal2> ...` No, your macro will break the template definition.

Comment: Oh darn, what was i thinking.